# How do I create a Debian package for a python program?

Tags: debian, software-installation, python, deb

I created a python game that I want to distribute on my website via a Debian package. The game has a few dependencies that are usually not installed (such as pygame) on some Linux computers, but often are available through aptitude. Also, it uses more then one python script file.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading about Debian packaging in general: https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

Comment: Read also python specific docs like https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ and https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide and have a look into the sources of python programs similar to your game.